# Question of including quotation or not.

Tags: quotations

When I write : My parent never told me that some criminals are being executed,

Do I add a quotation mark before some and after executed when I am using "that"?

Comment: No.  It's clearly not a direct quote, so no quotations marks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As your sentence stands, it is a **report structure**. You are not claiming that you are repeating your parent's actual words. Use of quotation marks, on the other hand, is understood to show a **quote structure**, where the words are claimed to be exactly as [here, your parent] uttered them. 'That' is used most often with report structures. But not exclusively:

From [Pasco-Hernando State College Writing Center](http://www.phccwritingcenter.org/?page_id=874) [tweaked]:

> A1 *He said, “It will rain today.”*
>
> B1 *He said, “It is absolutely certain that it will rain today.”*
>
> See how the signal phrase [often known confusingly as the reporting clause] is limited 
>   to words that say who says the quote.
>
> When more words are added before the quote, the quote becomes
>   fragmentary – a partial sentence quote.
>
> One example is the use of the word *that* before a quote. Then, the
>   quoted words would be part of a sentence started outside the quote:
>
> B2 *He said that “it will rain today.”*

Comment: Mind you don't get tweaked.

Comment: Huh? Tweaked???

Comment: eg having a colon removed.

Comment: It's Sunday, Mr. Ashworth, you know, the day the Lord rested?

Comment: @LittleEva - Spoken like a true colonist.